# Using integrals in electric field in ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, integration

When finding the electric field due to a ring. We take on the cos component as the sin component gets cancelled out. Now if we integrate the sin component of  the electric field of the sin component should it come 0?.According to me when we integrate the sin components it should not come zero as integral is simply a summation and it does not subtract. Is my reasoning correct?

[image]

Comment: Can you show you integration? I believe you are confusing the angle $\theta$ with the angle representing the integration coordinates.

Comment: I could but I dont know how to use latex

Comment: I recommend you to learn. A useful link is:  https://es.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tutorials.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the MathJax used on this site.

Comment: I've seen some comment discussion arise which critically depends on knowing exactly which integral is being done. Consequently I'm putting this question on hold until that is clarified by editing the integral into the post.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why we do not take the sin component and integrate is because there is a direction factor too that the integral does not take care of.

It just adds up all the magnitudes, however it does not take into account that due to opposite directions they cancel out.

But for the horizontal component, all the directions are the same. So you can proceed either by integration or by logical addition.

If you want to do the vertical component by integration, you could split it into 2 seperate integration, each involving the same direction of field.

And then you could vectorially add them. Due to the opposite directions you arithmatically subtract them.

I will leave that part up to you. However it should come out to be 0.

Comment: Thanks this was the answer I was looking for

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. It's an integral of a vector-valued function, so it _does_ take care of the direction component... right?

Comment: @DavidZ But I think the integrand the user is asking about is a scalar. He split the field seperately into X and Y directions. However when he integrated the term E.sin theta ,i.e the vertical component, he got a non zero value. This is not a vector if you observe, as directions are not taken into account

Comment: No I'm asking about a vector

Comment: The components are also vectors

Comment: Could you specify what that vector component is?

Comment: @BlackSusanoo but as per your question you just integrated the sin components. If i understand it as dE.sin theta, it is just a scalar factor.

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNACHILAKAMARRI wont't the half ring below the x axis make -ve angle (as taken clockwise) hence sin$\theta$ will be -ve ?

Comment: @Bhavay Yes if you consider it that way. But if you consider $/theta $ as a constant that does not even change sign, then integating as such wont give you a non zero answer. I think the user got a non zero value because he did not consider 2 different signs of theta